# Displaying scrollable widget in Android

Tags: android, css

We are using Ajax call to fetch a list of strings and display using a widget on JSP page developed for android web application.

We are facing the issue as strings are displayed limited to the widget’s size and not scrollable in the android emulator. However, the same code works fine in Internet explorer on desktop.

The css used for the above widget is: 
jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css

Class in the above css specific to widget display:

```
.ui-autocomplete {

                position: absolute;

                cursor: default;

                max-height: 100px;

                overflow-y: auto;

                /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */

                overflow-x: hidden;

                /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */

                padding-right: 20px;

}
```

The overflow-y: auto enables the vertical scrollbar in IE but the same doesn’t on Android Emulator.

Any help or pointers to enable the above functionality in android would be great

Answer (score 1):

The Android browser has a bug that causes overflow:auto to be treated as overflow:hidden.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2911

I'm not aware of a workaround for this; you might want to reformat the page for mobile.